# Hyperledger fabric endorsement policy error using Java SDK

Tags: java, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric-sdk-java

I am working on golang version of fabcar smart contract while seeking to implement a Java-SDK API which enrolls an admin, registers a user and performs query-update value operations based on https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/tree/master/fabcar/java

I have successfully set up a 3 org-9 peers blockchain network, installed, instantiated and invoked chaincode on peers.

However, as i am working on implementing the relative API, i am only able to successfully query blockchain database, while getting a "Could not meet endorsement policy for chaincode mycc"

Please find below screenshot of relative error

[image]

Endorsement policy is "OR ('Org1MSP.member','Org2MSP.member', 'Org3MSP.member')".

Should registered user somehow get an Org1/Org2/Org3.member attribute? Any leads would be appreciated!

Comment: Are you sure this is the instantiated policy? Have you upgraded the chaincode? When you upgrade the chaincode you need to define endorsement policy.

Comment: @SergioGragera yes this is the instantiated policy. No need to upgrade chaincode. I successfully queried and wrote to ledger with Java API, by  updating /etc/hosts file to include all peers,db's and CA's as localhosts.

Comment: @StamGR In my case this was caused by a typo in the method name :(

Comment: @StamGR what does your host file look like? I have the same issue. Help appreciated

Comment: @rogger2016 my host file looks something like this:

127.0.0.1 localhost
127.0.0.1 orderer[i].<domain>.com
127.0.0.1 peer[i].<org>.<domain>.com
127.0.0.1 ca.<org>.<domain>.com
127.0.0.1 couchdb[i]

where i=1,2.3... (depending on the number of peers/orderers etc.) while <org> and <domain> is case dependent. hope it helps

Comment: Thanks @StamGR, ill check it put :)

Comment: the host file changes worked :) Cheers @StamGR

Comment: @StamGR also make sure your chaincode argument types are the same on both sides (chaincode vs. app)

Answer (score 0):

Like @Ikar Pohorský said, for me this got resolved after I used correct method name. Also, ensure that you delete 'wallet' folder in order to regenerate the user if your HLF n/w was recreated.

```
@Test
public void testMyMethodToBeInvoked() throws Exception {
    deleteDirectory(".\\wallet");
    EnrollAdmin.main(null);
    RegisterUser.main(null);
    // Load a file system based wallet for managing identities.
    final Path walletPath = Paths.get("wallet");
    final Wallet wallet = Wallet.createFileSystemWallet(walletPath);

    // load a CCP
    final Path networkConfigPath = Paths
            .get("C:\\sw\\hlf146-2\\fabric-samples\\first-network\\connection-org1.yaml");

    final Gateway.Builder builder = Gateway.createBuilder();
    builder.identity(wallet, "user1").networkConfig(networkConfigPath).discovery(true);

    // create a gateway connection
    try (Gateway gateway = builder.connect()) {
        final Network network = gateway.getNetwork("mychannel");
        final Contract contract = network.getContract("mycc");

        String myJSONString="{\"a\":\"b\"}";

        byte[] result;
        // Following did NOT work. Control goes directly to 'invoke' when 'submitTransaction' is done directly. 'invoke' need not be mentioned here.
        // result = contract.submitTransaction("invoke", myJSONString);

        // Following DID work. In chaincode (my chain code was Java) I had a method named 'myMethodToBeInvoked'. The chain code was written similar to https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/blob/release-1.4/chaincode/chaincode_example02/java/src/main/java/org/hyperledger/fabric/example/SimpleChaincode.java
        result = contract.submitTransaction("myMethodToBeInvoked", my);
        System.out.println(new String(result));
    }
}
```

EDIT: Also, please remember that if your chaincode throws errorResponse, even then we can have this endorsement fail issue. So, check if your chain code is working without any issues.